# Homework Help - AVL Tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, avl-tree

This is a homework question. I am only seeking help because I am very lost as to approaching this problem.

Instead of having the height of as the balance factor, this AVL tree has the size as the balance factor.

I have to prove that the height is O(log n).

---

### My thought

Approach 1
Since an AVL tree has a height of O(log n), I can basically prove that this is an AVL tree. So it would have the same height as a regular AVL tree. However, I am not sure how to do this completely. I essentially need to show that the height of one side is at most +/- 1 relative to the other. If it is, then it would be an AVL tree.

Approach 2
I can prove the Omega(log n) fairly easily, I can use the best case where it is balanced and that in that case, the height is log(n).

After that, I can try to prove the Big O case. This is the part that I am unsure about. I have no clue how to show that the upper bound of the height is log(n).

Could someone nudge me to the right direction please? Which approach is suggested?

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that the first approach will work out - the condition for an AVL tree is probably not equivalent to the description you have. The second approach is more feasible.

Here's a further hint : Induct. Or perhaps in more CS terms, recurse :) Can you prove that the required height property is true for all modified-AVL trees with `n` nodes? If so, you know that this property is already true for your right and left subtrees. What can you do with that?

EDIT : More detailed answer - Assume that you have proved that for all trees with at most `N` nodes, the height is bounded by `c log N`, for some sufficiently large `c`. Given a tree with `N+1` nodes, let `L` and `R` be the number of nodes in its left and right subtrees, respectively. Since `L<=N` and `R<=N`, by our induction assumption, both these subtrees have heights bounded by `c log (number of nodes)`. The height of full tree is bounded above by `1 + max(c log L, c log R)`. Now, `L+R=N`, `L<=2R` and `R<=2L` giving `L<2N/3` and `R<2N/3`. So, `max(log L, log R) < log(2N/3) = log N + log(2/3)`. `1 + c*max(log L, log R) < 1 + c*log N + c*log(2/3) < c*log(N+1)`, for sufficiently large `c`.